# Apache Serving 403 Forbidden after OS X Snow Leopard Upgrade to Version 10.6.6

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

I've just upgraded my MacBook Pro to OS X Snow Leopard version 10.6.6 and now Apache is misbehaving:

- requests to http://localhost/ generate a 403 Forbidden response **-- FIXED**
- requests to any of my virtual hosts seem to generate a 200 Ok response, but contain zero bytes

Some further info that might be useful:

- I'm using the Apache that comes bundled with OS X.
- I'm using PHP from http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/ (which is in /usr/local/bin)

I've had look at the Apache error log and the only error seems to be the following:

> [notice] child pid 744 exit signal
>   Segmentation fault (11)

I'm completely stumped by this. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Ok, I've managed to resolve the 403 Forbidden error thanks to http://techtrouts.com/mac-os-x-105-web-sharing-forbidden-403-on-httplocalhostusername/

I'm still having the second problem though for *any* request e.g. this now happens when I request http://localhost

**FURTHER UPDATE**
Changing the Apache config files to use the version of PHP 5.3 that comes with Snow Leopard gets rid of the error. However that's not ideal for me as I need to use PHP 5.2 (as I've got some Drupal 6 sites to work on that break when using PHP 5.3).

**FURTHER FURTHER UPDATE**
Although this didn't actually get resolved it is no longer an issue for me (I'm no longer tied to using PHP 5.2).

Comment: did you try to recompile php 5.2 with the new apache?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [macports](http://www.macports.org/) instead of the OS X builtins. You can relatively easily install whatever versions of software you want, and you don't have to worry about OS X updates breaking your sites.

After you install macports run:

```
sudo port sync
```

To install php5.2 with apache2 and mysql5 you'd run:

```
sudo port install php52 +apache2 +mysql5
```

`port variants php52` will show you what other options you have.